# How to Set the Checkbox on the left side of the text

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

In my android application, I have a checkbox and some text associate with it. By default the texts are in the right side and the checkbox in left side but checkbox and text are not in the same line and checkbox is in the next line, how can i fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="55dip"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change linearlayout orientation to horizontal.

Comment: Gopal Rao thank you , it works ;)

Comment: and how can i set the space between checkbox and text?

Comment: I fix it with layout_marginLeft and layout_marginLeft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the orientation of your Linear Layout to horizontal or you can just add android:text="CHECKBOX TEXT" to your checkbox.